# What properties do we synthesize in xcode 4.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode4.4

I am using Xcode 4.4.1. When I define  `@property`  like `UINavigationController` or `NSArray`in .h file I have to `@synthesize` it in .m file. But some `@property` like `UITabBarController` or `NSString` I don't have to `@synthesize` it to make it work.

My Question is what `@property`s need to `@synthesize` and what need not to.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
UITabBarController *_tabBar;
UINavigationController *_navBar;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Employee *empView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *_tabBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *_navBar;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize _navBar;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
Employee *emp = [[Employee alloc]initWithNibName:@"Employee" bundle:nil];
self._tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self._navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:emp];
self._tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_navBar, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self._tabBar;
self._navBar.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

When I `@synthesize` `UINavigationController` I get `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`. But when I don't  `@synthesize` `UINavigationController` I don't get `UINavigationController` but `UITabBarController` is displayed.

In both cases I didn't `@synthesize` `UITabBarController`

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some code?  Here's a quick tutorial on `@property` and `@synthesize`: http://www.optictheory.com/iphone-dev/2010/02/objective-c-primer-part-3-property-and-synthesize/

Comment: @WendiKidd Please see the question again I did some editing to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the last version of the compiler (LLVM) shipped with Xcode 4.4, the `@synthesize` directive is not needed anymore.

Every `@property` you declare for which you don't use `@synthesize`explicitly will have its accessor synthesized automatically as if you wrote `@synthesize yourprop = _yourprop;`. That's a new feature of the latest compiler (as before you had to write `@synthesize` (or implement the accessors) for all your `@properties` explicitly).

*Note that of course you can still use the `@synthesize` property explicitly if you prefer to (just like old times). This can be a way to explicitly design the backing instance variable to use for the property. But as a matter of fact **I strongly recommend to forget about instance variables** (in fact that's ages I don't use explicit instance variables between the curly braces of my `@interface` declaration anymore), and only work with `@property` declarations. With that and the new feature that let the compiler generate the `@synthesize` directives for you, you will avoid a lot of glue code and make your classes more compact to write.*

---

FYI you can **toggle a warning** when you have a `@property` for which is implicitly synthesized (meaning for which you didn't write the `@synthesize` directive explicitly thus for which the compiler now synthesize it for you). Simply go to the Build Settings of your project and turn on the "Implicit Synthesized Properties" warning (under "Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 - Warnings - Objective-C" section), and the compiler will tell you about all the properties for which it implicitly synthesize the accessors as you didn't mention the `@synthesize` directive yourself.

Comment: Please read my answer again. (1) Not explicitly `@synthesize` makes the compiler generate a `@synthesize propname = _propname`, so in your cas it generates `@synthesize _navBar = __navBar`, thus generates an ivar named `__navBar` that is different from your `_navBar` ivar. This explains why `self._navBar` is not `nil` and neither is `__navBar`, but the `_navBar` ivar is `nil`. But you use it directly in the `self._tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_navBar, nil];` line (instead of using the property or the associated `__navBar` ivar).

Comment: (2) so as I stated in my answer, I strongly recommend to stop declaring ivars (that was never necessary since the first release of iOS, by the way, as `@synthesize` has always generated ivars when needed) and thus remove the `UINavigationController *_navBar;` declaration in your `@interface` method (you will understand your mistake right away then), and moreover I also strongly recommand to avoid prefixing your `@property` names with an underscore (as that adds some confusion between the property and its backing instance variable)

Comment: Final note, if all the above was not clear enough: writing `@synthesize _navBar` explicitly is the same as writing `@synthesize _navBar = _navBar`, namely the property `_navBar` uses the ivar `_navBar` (same name as the prop) as its backing store. Whereas when you don't write the `@synthesize` property is the same as writing `@synthesize _navBar = __navBar`, namely the name of the generated ivar (used as a backing store for the property) is the name of the property **preceded by an underscore**. Thus your property is then not associated with the `_navBar` ivar but with the `__navBar` ivar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now things are making sense for me. :-)

Comment: can you please tell me why it is not the same in the case of UITabbarController.

Comment: It is the same for the `_tabBar` property : if you don't `@synthesize` it explicitly, it will generate an `__tabBar` ivar as a backing store for the `_tabBar` property, and the `_tabBar` ivar will not be bound to the property at all and will be just another standalone ivar. But because you never use the `_tabBar` instance variable directly in your code (as opposed to the `_navBar` instance variable that you use in the line I pointed out instead of using `self._navBar`), the problem is not revealed by your code. But still, `_tabBar` will be `nil` but `self._tabBar` and `__tabBar` won't.