# Interface Builder IBOutlet - no @synthesize

Tags: ios, xcode4, iboutlet

I'm using XCode 4.4.1 to learn iPhone dev.

I'm creating outlet properties in my ABCViewController.h header by dragging from the 'Referencing Outlets' section in the pop-up menu for a UIObject. This adds lines such as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
```

to the header file.

Now when I view the corresponding ABCViewController.m file I'm expecting to see

```
@synthesize nameField;
```

auto-generated somewhere. But it isn't - I have to add each @synthesize statement manually.

It's only a minor niggle, but I'd like to know what's going wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449005/what-properties-do-we-synthesize-in-xcode-4-4-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode 4.4 (specifically, the LLVM 4.0 Compiler), synthesis of properties happens by default if there's no @synthesize directive.  It's equivalent to:

```
@synthesize nameField = _nameField;
```